# Tabular One column over two rows

Tags: tables, multirow, supertabular

I have a problem inside an already complicated tabular. The Column with the “Lekta” has to go to the bottom of the tabular and has to close there. I think it has to be possible with multirow but I am unable to succeed…

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}


\begin{supertabular}{p{1.418cm}p{3.128cm}|p{3.467cm}|p{4.1270003cm}|}
\hhline{~~--}
 &
 &
\multicolumn{2}{p{7.7940006cm}|}{\textbf{Circumstance}}\\\hhline{~~--}
 &
 &
\textbf{Same} &
\textbf{Different}\\\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|p{1.418cm}|}{\textbf{Lekta}} &
\textbf{Same } &
Always in agreement

 &
Never in agreement or disagreement

\\\hline
 &
\textbf{Different \& }\textbf{contradictory} &
Always in disagreement

 &
Sometimes in disagreement\\\hhline{~---}
\end{supertabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Those blank lines make a difference.  Do you really want them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution based on`ltablex`, which combines the functionalities of `longtable` and `tabularx`. I supposed the widths for your `p(somelength)` were calculated by some software. This can be replaced with the `>{\hsize= xx\hsize}` directive  if you need to adjust the widths of the  `X` columns. The remaining`p{…}` column in the following code was replaced with `m{…}` to ensure vertical centring of the contents of the cells.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{1.418cm}|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X|}%m{3.128cm}
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
                                               &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Circumstance}}\\
  \cline{3-4}
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
                                               &
  \textbf{Same} &
  \textbf{Different}\\\hline
  \multirow{4}{1.418cm}[1.8ex]{\textbf{Lekta}} &
  \textbf{Same } &
  Always in agreement
                                               &
  Never in agreement or disagreement\\
  \cline{2-4}
                                               &
  \textbf{Different \& }\textbf{contradictory} &
  Always in disagreement
                                               &
  Sometimes in disagreement\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right – the tabular was created by the tool writer2latex. Funny to see a very similiar result done quite differently!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\multicolumn` to remove as well as add vertical lines.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but it made sense to me.  The big problem is where to locate "Lekta" vertically within the space.  Frankly, the easiest solution is to play with `[fixup]` until it looks the way you want.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{supertabular}{|p{1.418cm}|p{3.128cm}|p{3.467cm}|p{4.1270003cm}|}
\hhline{~~--}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }&
 &
\multicolumn{2}{p{7.7940006cm}|}{\textbf{Circumstance}}\\ \hhline{~~--}
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{ }&
 &
\textbf{Same} &
\textbf{Different}\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{1.418cm}[1.5ex]{\textbf{Lekta}} &
\textbf{Same } &
Always in agreement
 &
Never in agreement or disagreement
\\ \cline{2-4}
 & \raggedright
\textbf{Different \& }\textbf{contradictory} &
Always in disagreement
 &
Sometimes in disagreement\\ \hline
\end{supertabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW, the \multirow is not really needed here, since the contents don't span more than one row.